# Slideshow navigation arrow links not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am just getting started with programming and am building my own website in Kirby. I want to implement a carousel slider in my website and followed this tutorial (https://youtu.be/9HcxHDS2w1s). I did everything exactly as shown but I cannot click on my arrows and so the slides don't change. Everything else looks to be fine, it's just the links I think.

**Here's the html:**

```
    <div class="carousel-h" data-carousel>
        <button class="carousel-button-h prev-h" data-carousel-button="prev-h">
        <img src="<?= url('assets/icons/button-prev.svg') ?>"></button>
        <button class="carousel-button-h next-h" data-carousel-button="next-h">
        <img src="<?= url('assets/icons/button-next.svg') ?>">
        </button>
        <ul data-slides> 
            <li class="slide-h" data-active>
                <img src="images/Fokuss_Poster_web.jpg" alt="">
            </li> 
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Rebooth_mockup_prints_web.jpg" alt="">
            </li>  
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Kushim_Thumbnail_web.jpg" alt="">
            </li>  
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Savo_Mockup_web.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Foto_Zine_2Sem_12-web.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Subspace_Mockup_web_0.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slide-h">
                <img src="images/Zeitung_Vision_06-web.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

**This is the javascript:**

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click",  () => {
        const offset = button.dataset.carouselButton === "next" ? 1 : -1
        const slides = button
        .closest("[data-carousel]")
        .querySelector("[data-slides]")

    const activeSlide = slides.querySelector("[data-active]")
    let newIndex = [...slides.children].indexOf(activeSlide) + offset
    if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = slides.children.length -1
    if (newIndex >= slides.children.length) newIndex = 0

    slides.children[newIndex].dataset.active = true
    delete activeSlide.dataset.active
    })
})
```

**And the css:**

```
.carousel-h {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-h > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.slide-h {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.slide-h > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.slide-h[data-active] {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.carousel-button-h {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 999;
    border: none;
    font-size: 3rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.carousel-button-h.prev-h {
    left: 1rem;
}

.carousel-button-h.next-h {
    right: 1rem;
}
```

I did replace the arrows used in the tutorial with my own svgs and thought that could be a problem but I also tried it with the HTML code for arrows from toptal and that makes no difference.

I tried my best to find the mistake but can't figure it out so I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your js code. You are using `forEach` over an undefined variable! If you pay attention you'll see that you haven't defined `buttons` in your code. So let's make your code work:

> 1. First you have to select all the buttons in the page by using `getElementsByTagName`.

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

> 2. Now you have selected all the buttons in the page BUT the type of the buttons variable is `object` and note that it's **not** possible to use forEach over an object. So in order to use `forEach`, you have to convert the object to an array using the code below:

```
const buttonsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons);
```

Now you have your buttons list array ready to be used in your code.
You JS code should look like this:

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const buttonsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons);
buttonsList.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click",  () => {
        const offset = button.dataset.carouselButton === "next" ? 1 : -1
        const slides = button
        .closest("[data-carousel]")
        .querySelector("[data-slides]")

    const activeSlide = slides.querySelector("[data-active]")
    let newIndex = [...slides.children].indexOf(activeSlide) + offset
    if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = slides.children.length -1
    if (newIndex >= slides.children.length) newIndex = 0

    slides.children[newIndex].dataset.active = true
    delete activeSlide.dataset.active
    })
})
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons);` should be replaced with `Array.from(buttons)`  or `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")` then `buttons.forEach(...`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Both your solutions work in a normal file but not within Kirby, so that seems to be another problem which is probably better suited for the Kirby forum.